# Google Analytics View for a large list of IP Addresses

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We have a large amount of "internal traffic" that we want to filter to a separate view in Google Analytics. These are people that work for us but are in multiple locations. To be specific, I have over 2,000 ip addresses for this group of people.

When I try to set up a filter for this traffic, using regex, the character limit on the text box doesn't allow this many IP addresses.

[image: Imgur]

The Filter Pattern field just isn't big enough to hold more than a few addresses. Any ideas how else I can import these addresses to set up a separate view or segment in Google Analaytics?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on Michele's and Eike's answer and trying to sum this up into 1 comprehensive answer. Your options:

- **Multiple filters:** break down the rule into several smaller filters
- **Subnetting**: define the rule as a collection of subnets instead of individual IP addresses. Tools like this one http://wintelguy.com/subnetcalc.pl might help you.
- **Custom Dimension Filter**: for instance by providing a mechanism (eg `?internal`) in the URL for people to tag themselves as being internal traffic. Example: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/block-internal-traffic-gtm/
- **ISP Filter**: if some of those 2K people work in the same offices and those offices are serviced by corporate ISPs, you can the [`ISP/Network Location`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=geo_network&jump=ga_networkdomain) built-in dimension to exclude those. When I work with large corporates with multiple offices around the world, it's very common that most traffic comes from ISPs named `{company} ltd`, `{company} germany gmbh`, `{company} italia spa` etcc... so I can filter with the company name instead of using IPs, very useful. To find out if you can use that method, have a look at the **Audience -> Network -> Service Provider** report to see what source ISPs are being used.
- **Test/QA Server**: if those 2K people work for you to do testing etc..., you could have them access a test/qa/acceptance version of your site and simply use a different tracker for that one.

Comment: Using the link in the "Custom Dimension Filter" line worked great! Google Tag Manager allows a ton of characters in the tags that allowed me to put in a Regex formula listing the 2300 ip addresses!

Answer (score 1):

Just separate the list of IP in multiple filters (the number of filters you'll need will depend on how much your regex will be optimized).

Comment: That's roughly 48 filters. Is there any other way to segment this group of IP addresses?

Comment: If you have, for example, a range of IP from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.255 you can exclude all these 255 IP with a regex like this: 192.168.0.* anyway, the solution that I mentioned before is also the same recommended by Google "If you have multiple IP addresses or subnets to exclude, you can make more than one filter. As with all filters, make sure the conditions you specify don't interfere with or contradict each other.". Ref: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034840?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

At this point I would suggest you move the logic to your website - set a custom dimension in your tracking code depending on if the users IP is on a list of "internal" addresses or not, and then use the dimension in your filter. With that many addresses it seems like to more maintainable solution, especially if you have multiple views.

Comment: This was basically what I did but used Google Tag Manager to take care of most of this!